# Quitar ceros o cero de delante de datos

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Tengo unos datos metidos en una tabla.
Os pongo ejemplo

codcliente    |    nombre
010               juan
011               pepe
012               luis

Necesito quitar el cero que hay delante de cada codigo cliente.
Estoy haciendolo sobre pgadmin y no encuentro nada que me pueda ayudar.
He estado mirando como tratar cadenas con sql pero no veo nada relacionado para quitar los ceros.

Gracias.

Comment: y la funcion to_number no sirve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podés usar una combinación de las funciones `REPLACE` y `LTRIM` de SQL, algo así:

```
SELECT REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(tuCadena, '0', ' ')),' ', '0')
```

---

La función `Replace` justamente reemplaza una cadena por otra que le indiques. Por ejemplo, si tengo la cadena "SQL Tutorial y quiero formar "HTML Tutorial", haría algo así:

`SELECT REPLACE('SQL Tutorial', 'SQL', 'HTML');`

Donde el primer parámetro es la cadena completa, el segundo lo que quiero reemplazar, y el tercero lo que quiero insertar.

Luego, la función `LTRIM` simplemente elimina los espacios a la izquierda de una cadena.

Entendiendo todo esto y volviendo a tu caso:

```
SELECT REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(tuCadena, '0', ' ')),' ', '0')
```

El `REPLACE` más interno modifica todos los 0 por espacios. Luego elimino solo los espacios del principio con `LTRIM`, y luego vuelvo a reemplazar los espacios que quedaron con ceros.

Answer (score 1):

Si casteas el código a entero se autoredondeará al número sin los 0

```
SELECT CAST('010' AS int)       -->10
SELECT CAST('00120' AS int)     -->120
SELECT CAST('00000107' AS int)  -->107
```